# How to run two tasks with different Schedulers via Flux

Tags: spring, flux, reactor

I try store and parse&store some raw data with two strategies (serial & parallel)

```
    Flux<PanasonicData> f = Flux.create(sink -> dataRepo.addConsumer(sink::next));
    Flux.from(f).publishOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe(this::save1);
    Flux.from(f).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()).map(MyClass::parse).subscribe(this::save2);
```

Or

```
    ConnectableFlux<PanasonicData> cf = Flux.create(sink -> dataRepo.addConsumer(sink::next)).publish();
    cf.autoConnect().publishOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe(this::save1);
    cf.autoConnect().publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()).map(MyClass::parse).subscribe(this::save2);
```

But the second task is never ran !!!
How can i run this two tasks with this two different strategies?

Comment: I found the cause: One of the subscribers is suspended during execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the minimum number of subscribers via `autoConnect(int minSubscribers)`:

```
Flux<PanasonicData> cf = Flux.create(sink -> dataRepo.addConsumer(sink::next)).publish().autoConnect(2);
cf.publishOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe(this::save1);
cf.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()).map(MyClass::parse).subscribe(this::save2);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, But i found the cause: One of the subscribers is suspended during execution.

Comment: Ok, that’s great that you found a solution!